# How to let users add multiple tags using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I already have a script to let users enter tags but I want to let users enter multiple tags that are separated by a comma for example, `(html, css, php)` and store each tag in the database.

Is there a tutorial that can show me how to do this or can someone give me a couple of examples that i can work from.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a schema like this:

- Post (id, author_id, post_date, post_text);
- Tag (id, tag_name);
- Post Tag (id, post_id, tag_id).

The Post Tag table is what's called a *join table* for the many-to-many relationship from Post to Tag (because a Post can have multiple Tags and a Tag can be used on multiple Posts).

The user enters a list of tags separated by commas into an input field:

```
$tags = array_unique(array_map(explode(',', $POST['tags']), 'trim'));
```

and you have an array of tags the user entered. You may want to sanitize them further, like only allowing certain characters and/or converting them to lowercase.

Then your code becomes:

```
$post_id = ...
foreach ($tats as $tag) {
  $tag = mysql_real_escape_string($tag);
  $sql = <<<END
INSERT INTO PostTag (post_id, tag_id)
VALUES ($post_id, (SELECT id FROM Tag WHERE tag_name = '$tag'))
END;
  mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically what you'd do for tag<->post mappings is have 1 table for tags, 1 table for posts, and then a third table which stores pairings between them:

```
tagid tagname
-------------
1     foo
2     bar

postid posttitle
-------------
1      test
2      beep

tagid postid
-------------
1     2
2     1
2     2
```

Would have two posts, where the first is tagged "bar" and the second is tagged "foo, bar"

Comment: Is the question rather not about normalization but *how in fact* to normalize with CSV input?

Comment: I was looking for more how to let users add multiple tags and separating them apart and storing them. I already have the database designed.

Comment: Ah. In that case, `explode()` is probably the easiest way to parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could split a string of multiple tags using the PHP [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) command, and then save each tag to the database as you do now.

The following code would split the string "html, css, php" into an array ["html", "css", "php"]:

```
$tag_string = "html, css, php";
$tags = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $tag_string);
```